# What is the best option to transform an array to a json

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my array `var tags = ["Shisha rauchen", "Indischecurryfürze"]`

What I'm trying

```
import React from 'react'

function Interests(tags) {

    console.log(tags)
    var myJson = JSON.parse(tags);
    console.log(myJsonString)
    return (
        <div>
            hi
            {myJson.map((tag, index) => {
                return (
               {tag}
               );
              })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Interests
```

But I'm getting the following error `TypeError: myJsonString.map is not a function`

So what is the best option to transform the array `tags` to an json or that I could using the `map` methpd

Comment: `var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(tags);` Why do you have this line? It will convert your array to string.

Comment: Stringifying the array is nonsense in the first place; just map over your `tags` array. This is why w3schools is bad, people.

Comment: Please show the value of `tag`

Comment: You don't want JSON here. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) That means that if you have JSON in JavaScript code, you have a **string**. Strings don't have a `map` method. As @ikhvjs said, just use `tags`, it's already what you want.

Comment: You don't need to parse ```tags``` because tags are already an array.

Comment: You are confused my the concept of a "JSON Array" however **there is no such thing**. What you have in the first line of your question *is already an array*, and you can just map over it. JSON doesn't enter in this picture at any point. JSON is a way to transmit or store arrays and objects in text format. You don't need it to render a list of tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error possibly due to the fact that you are not returning an element inside map. You cant render tags directly. Trt this

```
import React from 'react'

function Interests(tags) {

console.log(tags)
return (
    <div>
        hi
      {tags.map((tag, index) => <span key={index}{tag}</span>)}
    </div>
)
}
export default Interests
```

Comment: Thank you! You are the best! ♥

Comment: Your answer is just this: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is remove this line:

```
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(tags);
```

and do:

```
tags.map
```

This will make your array into a string. `"".map` will throw an error.

Read more about `JSON.stringify` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Answer (score 1):

It's normal your "myJsonString" it's now a string so you don't have method "map" on string.
Why you don't do like that:

```
import React from 'react'

function Interests(tags) {

    return (
        <div>
            hi
            {tags.map((tag, index) => {
                return (
               {tag}
               );
              })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Interests
```

What result do you want exactly?

Answer (score 0):

As [I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67870232/what-is-the-best-option-to-transform-an-array-to-a-json/67870343#comment119962657_67870232), you don't want JSON here. Just use the array you have, there's no reason to convert it into a string representation of an array (which is what `JSON.stringify` does).

Two things:

1. If `tags` is a prop, you need to pick that prop out of the props object your component function is called with, either with destructuring:

   ```
   function Interests({tags})
   // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^−−−−^
   ```

   Or by using a different name (like `props`) and using `props.tags` later when you want the tags.
2. If your goal is to output all of the tags as text, perhaps separated by spaces, all you need to do is `{tags.join(" ")}`. That joins the array together with spaces in-between, and outputs it to the component being rendered (the `div` in your case).

Taken together:

```
function Interests({tags}) {
    return (
        <div>
            hi {tags.join(" ")}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function Interests({tags}) {
    return (
        <div>
            hi {tags.join(" ")}
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Interests tags={["Shisha rauchen", "Indischecurryfürze"]} />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```